# how to exclude from counting holidays in rails4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to make an app for vacation requests but i am facing a problem.I have e model called VacationRequest and a view of VacationRequest where the result will be shown.

VacationRequest.rb model

```
def skip_holidays
  count1 = 0
  special_days = Date.parse("2017-05-09", "2017-05-12")

  special_days.each do |sd|
    if ((start_data..end_data) === sd)
      numero = (end_data - start_data).to_i 
      numro1 = numero - sd
    else
      numero = (end_data - start_data).to_i 
    end
  end
end
```

VacationRequest show.htm.erb

here i called the method from model

```
@vacation_request.skip_holidays
```

this is showing errors and is not working. Please help me with that!

Comment: Add the exact error message to the question

Comment: the loop .each is not taking all the array but only the first element of the array.I think this is suposed to go through each element end compare them.

Comment: It is throwing an error :

Comment: undefined method 'each' for Tue, 09  May 2017:Date

Comment: You aren't getting an array at all. `Date.parse("2017-05-09", "2017-05-12")` returns a single `Date` object.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to add holidays in an array and then exclude from counting when an employ makes a vacation request,since i am trying to do that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach to this would be the following:

```
def skip_holidays
  special_days = ["2017-05-09", "2017-05-12"].map(&:to_date)
  accepted_days = []
  refused_days = []
  (start_data..end_data).each do |requested_date|
    accepted_days << requested_date unless special_days.include?(requested_date)
    refused_days << requested_date if special_days.include?(requested_date)
  end
  accepted_day_count = accepted_days.count
  refused_days_count = refused_days.count
end
```

This way you iterated over all requested dates (the range), checked if the date is a special day - If so, refuse it, otherwise accept it.
In the end you can display statistics about accepted and refused dates.

Comment: Philipp yhanks a lot you really helped me,but i have another question.What does this line do:.map(&:to_date), because it skips the hole range of dates from 2017-05-09 to 2017-05-12 not only these two days.

Comment: In another comment you stated that you only want the two dates provided not to be count. The line of code takes each of the dates, runs the `to_date` method on them and returns the outcome as an array.

Comment: Thanks a lot Philipp,you really helped me.I wold like to know what does this line do: special_days = ["2017-05-09", "2017-05-12"].map(&:to_date),because is not taking only this two dates but the hole range from 2017-05-09 to 2017-05-12.

Comment: I am sorry if i confused you,  I want the dates i puted in special_days not to be count.Only the two dates i puted there.

Comment: You provide a range of dates (start_data to end_data). You want to count how many of those dates are NOT the same as your defined special_days, right? If so, that's exactly what I accomplished.

Comment: Special_days contains only the days where a employee has not to work because is a state holiday.So in special_days array  i want to exclude from counting only those days.For example: I chose the dates 2017-05-09 as start_date and 2017-05-13 as end_date.The result after susbstracting those days from special_days is one.

Comment: it should be 2 days

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a date range by passing multiple argument to the constructor. Instead call the constructor twice to create a range:

```
special_days = Date.parse("2017-05-09") .. Date.parse("2017-05-12")
```

Or if instead you want only the two dates, do:

```
special_days = ["2017-05-09", "2017-05-12"].map &:to_date
```

Comment: I want this two dates not to be count,so i want to put them in an array and then check if these days are one of the days a user has choosen and exclude from counting them,but i don't know how to do this.

Comment: this is the form of vacation_request controller from where a user selects start_date and end_date:

Answer (score 0):

This `Date.parse("2017-05-09", "2017-05-12")` don`t create a range, only return the first params parsed:

```
#irb
Date.parse("2017-05-09", "2017-05-12")
=> Tue, 09 May 2017
```

You can do it this way:

```
initial = Date.parse("2017-05-09")
final = Date.parse("2017-05-12")

((initial)..final).each do |date|
  #rules here.
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I did as you suggested me but still is showing only the first date.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to add holidays in an array and then exclude from counting when an employ makes a vacation request,since i am trying to do that!